usage and meaning of masquerade [to :PORT_SPEC]
Here is relevant example ruleset with 2 sample nftables NAT rules which masquerade IP from virtual machine to LAN:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

add table nat_4

# Sees all packets after routing, just before they leave the local system
add chain nat_4 postrouting_nat_4 {
    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
    comment "Postrouting SNAT IPv4 traffic"
}

# Masquerade all packets going from VMs to the LAN/Internet
add rule nat_4 postrouting_nat_4 meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter masquerade to :1024-65535

# Same rule as above but without [to :PORT_SPEC]
add rule nat_4 postrouting_nat_4 meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter masquerade

Sample IP address 192.168.122.0/24 is network address on which virtual machine operates.
I understand what masquerade does, it performs SNAT by changing source IP to outbound interface IP.
In that sense I understand what 2nd rule from the sample above does.
What's I don't understand is [to :PORT_SPEC] declaration (docs link), in the example (1st rule): masquerade to :1024-65535
What exactly does masquerade to :1024-65535 do and is it necessary to specify it?
Are those 2 rules basically the same or how are they different?
Which one is preferred to do NAT from virtual machine to internet over virtual switch on localhost?

I think things are clearer if you look at the documentation for the iptables MASQUERADE target. From iptables-extensions(8):

MASQUERADE
[...]

--to-ports port[-port]
This specifies a range of source ports to use, overriding
the default SNAT source port selection heuristics (see
above). This is only valid if the rule also specifies one
of the following protocols: tcp, udp, dccp or sctp.



The to :PORT_SPEC option in the NFT rule accomplishes the same thing: it specifies the source ports to use for masqueraded connections.

I see, source port mapping is enforced either automatically or manually specified, now if only I could also know the reason why source port mapping is necessary for SNAT or masquerade?

Because without port mapping the source ports would likely conflicts with services on the masquerade host.
